# print object in a array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have a api with json like this:

```
{

    "data": [
            {
            "carrier" : "abc",
            "extra": {

                "date": "1970-01-01" 

            },
            }
            {
            "carrier" : "abc",
            "extra": {

                "date": "1970-01-01" 

            },
            }
    ]
}
```

Then how can I use `date` and `carrier` in a map function.

I am using reactjs

Comment: above code is single object no need a map And `data:[key:vaue]` is invalid .Array don't have a key value pair .please check you object

Comment: @prasanth Edited

Comment: So what what kind of data do you want to come out of the map function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const obj = {
  "data": [
           {
            "carrier" : "abc",
            "extra": {
               "date": "1970-01-01" 
            },
            }
            {
            "carrier" : "abc",
            "extra": {

                "date": "1970-01-01" 

            },
            }
  ]
}

const newArray = object.data.map(ele => {
  return {
    carrier: ele.carrier,
    date: ele.extra && ele.extra.date
  };
})

// Result
[
  { carrier: "abc", date: "1970-01-01" },
  { carrier: "abc", date: "1970-01-01" }
]
```

Comment: But it is giving an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of undefined`

Comment: I modified the code to address the condition where extra is undefined.

Comment: Can you please explain the reason for this.

Comment: Definitely. Some of the objects in data do not have the `extra` key. I add the && operator to check if the `extra` key exists before reading the `date` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
const dataObj = {
  data: [
    {
      carrier: "abc",
      extra: {
        date: "1970-01-01"
      }
    },
    {
      carrier: "abc",
      extra: {
        date: "1970-01-01"
      }
    }
  ]
};

const dateArr = dataObj.data.map(obj => {
  return {
    date : obj.extra?.date,
    carrier : obj.carrier,
  }
});
```

> dateArr

```
[
  { carrier: "abc", date: "1970-01-01" },
  { carrier: "abc", date: "1970-01-01" }
]
```

Comment: Sorry, updated the question.

Comment: But it is giving an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of undefined`